# PostgreSQL: field names in "on conflict (...)" inside the function results table

Tags: postgresql

If there is a field in the description of the resulting table in the function declaration (for example, field1) that occurs in parentheses "***insert ... on conflict(field1)***", then an error occurs when executing the function:

```
SQL Error [42702]: ERROR: column reference "field1" is ambiguous
```

In order not to describe the problem for a long time and difficult, I immediately give an example of a ready-made test code with strange behavior:

Creating a table into which the row will be inserted :

```
drop table if exists testing_table;
create TABLE testing_table (
  -- Keep in mind the name of this field
  field1 int4
, s1 text
, constraint pk_testing_table_field1 PRIMARY key (field1)
);
```

Creating a function that inserts a row into a table

```
-- drop function if exists insert_testing_table;
create or replace function insert_testing_table(p_field1 int4, p_s1 text)
returns table 
(
  -- Keep in mind the name of this field
  field1 int4
  , s1 text
)
LANGUAGE plpgsql AS $function$
begin 

insert into testing_table as r (field1, s1) values (p_field1, p_s1)
on conflict (
-- It is this place that is the conflicting name that causes the error
field1
)
do update set s1 = p_s1 where r.field1 = p_field1;

return query select t.* from testing_table t where t.field1 = p_field1;

end $function$;
```

Calling a function:

```
select * from insert_testing_table(1, 'aaa');
```

This call will result in an error:

```
SQL Error [42702]: ERROR: column reference "field1" is ambiguous
```

You cannot specify either the alias, the name of the table, or the name of the constrain in parentheses of the expression "*on conflict(...)*", only the direct names of the fields of the table.

What does it mean: "*is ambiguous*"?
Which column of which table does the field1 column conflict with in the "*insert on conflict do update*" statement?

The error persists if I rename the field in the "*return query select...*" expression.

But **if I rename the "field1" field in the description of the resulting table, the function will run without error**.

How can I specify the name of the field in parentheses of the expression "on conflict(...)" to eliminate the error?

I understand that I can use:

`ON CONFLICT ON CONSTRAINT` *constraint_name*

But I want to sort out the abnormal situation with specifying the field in "on conflict(...)" , the same field that is in the description of the returning table.
What kind of strangeness is this?

Comment: You don't happen to have multiple indices on that column, do you?

Comment: @bergi , this is a completely ready-made test script, and in it only one key is created in the table. as you can see, the table is deleted and created. the script can be executed "as is".

Comment: Oh [I see it now](https://dbfiddle.uk/ug0e43jG). Looks like a bug to me, you should report this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative is to totally get rid of all variables other than the parameters ( p_...).  Postgres automatically creates a type definition  when a table is created with the same name as the table itself. You can use this as the return; you function declaration then essentially becomes `returns <table_name>`. Further when a conflict occurs Postgres generates an internal tuple with the declaration of the row being inserted. This tuple is referred to as `excluded.` with the same column names as the actual table. Also Postgres knows exactly what row  it was processing so there is no need to specify the `where`.  
Finally, in this case at least, this can be accomplished with a single statement and can be put into a SQL function - no pgplsql needed. So: (see [demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/1PsN-HG1))

```
create or replace function insert_testing_table(p_field1 int4, p_s1 text)
  returns testing_table
  language sql 
as $$
    insert into testing_table(field1, s1) 
         values (p_field1, p_s1)
         on conflict (field1)
         do update 
               set s1 = excluded.s1
         returning *;
$$;
```

Answer (score 1):

It is strange that PL/pgSQL tries to match a variable here; perhaps that's a bug.

Your options at this point are:

- give the column in the `RETURNS TABLE` clause a different, non-conflicting name
- use dynamic SQL:

  ```
  EXECUTE 'INSERT INTO testing_table as r (field1, s1)
           VALUES ($1, $2)
           ON CONFLICT (field1) DO UPDATE
           SET s1 = $2'
  USING p_field1, p_s1;
  ```
- put the `INSERT` statement into yet another function with different parameter names and call that

Comment: if you mean to add "r." to a field in the field list: `"insert into testing_table as r (` **r.field1** `, s1) values (p_field1, p_s1)"`, then this is a syntax error.    if you mean to add to `"on conflict(` **r.field1** `)"`, then as I wrote in the question - you cannot specify an alias in "on conflict(...)", this is also a syntactic error.

Comment: @Laurenz could you also explain what the ambiguity is in the first place?

Comment: if you execute the test script, you will see where the error occurs. I specifically marked the place in the function script that causes the error, it's right in the brackets of the expression "on conflict()", juast after the text : **"-- It is this place that is the conflicting name that causes the error"**

Comment: That surprises me, but you are right, I didn't try it. I have updated the answer.

Comment: Another solution is to [use `returns setof testing_table`](https://dbfiddle.uk/LMx9NnZl) instead of that `table` type definition. It seems more appropriate for the `return query select * from testing_table` anyway.

Comment: @Laurenz, yes, thank you. We are already using the third of the options you have suggested - the wrapper. Although double function calls are a small loss of performance, but we went for it. Unfortunately, we ourselves did not think to use the solution proposed by _Bergi_. Tomorrow we will finalize the code as _Bergi_ suggests.

Comment: @bergi, you should have posted this as an answer, I would have chosen it as a solution! thank you very much, tomorrow we will redo the code as you suggested!